# Is it possible to compile Vue.js templates to static HTML and CSS files?

Tags: webpack, vue.js

Recently I've fallen in love with Vue.js's [single file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html). It's so much nicer to have a component's template and styles close to each other, and I'm finding I write a lot fewer bugs now that it's so easy to componentise part of a page and use it in multiple places.

I'm wondering if I could extend this single-file component structure to generating static HTML pages, with no Vue involved.

For example, say I want to have a page that has a main "content" div containing a header, a section, and a footer. Using Vue.js, I can create 'header', 'section', and 'footer' components, and use JavaScript to have them instantiated after the page loads. Because each part of the page is in its own component, there's no chance of CSS in one component affecting another, and I have a much cleaner tree of files to edit.

However, this seems a little wasteful, as these components aren't actually interactive: I'm not using `v-model` or `v-bind` or `v-on`, I'm just using Vue.js because it lets me separate pieces of pages out. It also means my page won't work at all if JavaScript is disabled, since every single element (save the main content div) is dependent on Vue being available.

So is there any way I can compile .vue files, not to a page that loads these components at runtime using Vue.js, but to separate HTML and CSS files that render without any JavaScript?

Ideally, I'd have a component 'greeting.vue':

```
<template>
    <p class="greeting">Hello!</p>
</template>
<style scoped>
    .greeting { color: red; }
</style>
```

Used within a page:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <greeting></greeting>
    </body>
</html>
```

And these would compile into two files: an HTML page with the template compiled and pre-rendered, and a CSS file that contains the styles for all the components. I could then include the generated stylesheet in the page, and all the components would be styled.

I've looked at [vue-loader](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader) and [vueify](https://github.com/vuejs/vueify), but I can't understand what they're doing since I haven't used Webpack or Browserify enough.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are looking for is Server Side rendering. I would suggest you to have a look at Nuxt.js.

[From VueJS docs:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html#Nuxt-js)

> Properly configuring all the discussed aspects of a production-ready
> server-rendered app can be a daunting task. Luckily, there is an
> excellent community project that aims to make all of this easier:
> Nuxt.js. Nuxt.js is a higher-level framework built on top of the Vue
> ecosystem which provides an extremely streamlined development
> experience for writing universal Vue applications. Better yet, you can
> even use it as a static site generator (with pages authored as
> single-file Vue components)! We highly recommend giving it a try.

It is super simple to get it [started](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation). If you use `vue-cli`:

```
$ vue init nuxt/starter <project-name>
```

It comes with all you normally need (Vuex, Router,..). Just keep in mind that it enforces some folder structure, that you have to follow.

[Here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/commands) is the list of commands that are included in the starter.

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nuxt",
  "build": "nuxt build",
  "start": "nuxt start",
  "generate": "nuxt generate"
}
```

You will probably be mostly interested in the `generate` command, as it

> Build the application and generate every route as a HTML file (used
> for static hosting).

Also cool thing to note is that the project seems to be (at the time of writing this) [under active development](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js) and we can look forward to more great features!

Comment: This was what I ended up using.

Answer (score 10):

From the official vuejs guide:

> If you’re using Webpack, you can easily add prerendering with the [prerender-spa-plugin](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin). It’s been extensively tested with Vue apps - and in fact, the creator is a member of the Vue core team.

Comment: If anybody's wondering, this doesn't work for Vue 3.

Comment: `prerender-spa-plugin` is deprecated and repo is archived.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you can't do this because `Vue` uses a virtual DOM, it doesn't compile templates to `HTML` but to JavaScript `render functions` which is necessary to efficiently patch the DOM when data is updated.

I'm sure it's  possible to do what you want to do with a bit of `node` magic to parse and output files, but that would be quite a large undertaking for something that would only have a minimal effect.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that Vue.js by itself wouldn't be the tool to do this. It's just that the only place I've ever seen single-file components has been in Vue, so that's my reference point.

Answer (score 0):

There are many plugins.

Install Vue Meta for smaller projects. If you only have a few static pages I'd recommend Vue meta and then creating a few HTML files for the same pages by hand or using a prerendering service.

The problem with prerendering is its only available with certain setups and can be difficult to install if you don't already have the ideal setup requiring you to rebuilt it over again for optimizing SEO and prerendering in Vue.js

For this reason I recommend the following:

For small apps: Vue Meta

npm install vue-meta --save

For medium to large apps with dynamic rendering:

nuxt.js with SSR (Server Side Rendering):

See this video search on YouTube for more information on how to build a web app with nuxt.js and SSR:

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=nuxt+js+and+ssr

Answer (score 0):

You can build your app in multi-page mode using the `pages` Vue config. See https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages for details.