# Use VueJs to save a template

Tags: static, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My project currently is made with VueJS. Now, we need to process a certain template with the input data, then store the result and use it to send an email (for example).

Can i render a template with the user data and save it? how?

I don't want to use another library for this purpose, unless We can't do with VueJS

I have read about SSR. But i don't want to use a server-side rendering. The idea is only render certain messages. Following a behavior like this:

```
save: function(){
    userNote.user = ...
    userNote.message = document.getElementById('message').innerHtml;
    saveToServer(userNote);
}
```

The Message template:

```
<div id="message"> Dear {{user.name}}, please confirm that {{notes}} before {{date}}</div>
```

I hope i made me understand. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to compile Vue.js templates to static HTML and CSS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857376/is-it-possible-to-compile-vue-js-templates-to-static-html-and-css-files)

Comment: @thanksd Thanks, The question that you mentioned is very similar, but it isn't what i want. I'll add more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your template is stored in a component, you could add an export method :

```js
var templateComponent = Vue.component("template-component", {
  template: "<p>Hello {{name}}</p>",
  props: ["name"],
  methods: {
    exportHTML: function() {
      return this.$el.outerHTML;
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: "David",
    html: undefined
  },
  methods: {
    getHTML: function() {
      this.html = this.$refs.template.exportHTML();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div style="display: none">
        <template-component :name="name" ref="template"></template-component>
    </div>

    <label>Name
        <input v-model="name">
    </label>

    <button @click="getHTML">Get html</button>

    <pre>{{ html }}</pre>
</div>
```

Then you just have to call the exportHTML method on the template component to retrieve the HTML.

Comment: This works, in this example. I need to be aware the position of the children elements. If i add other child, i might be careful where i'll put it.

Comment: I've slightly edited my answer to access the template in a better way.