# Compile Vue.js to static HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I would like to be able to take a Vue.js component and compile it to static html (ideally at runtime). I do not need any javascript but I do need styles. I'm looking for a library where I could run something along the lines of this:

SomeNestedComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="world">
    World!
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
.world {
  background: blue;
}
```

```
const vueComponent = `
<template>
  <div class="hello">Hello!</div>
  <SomeNextedComponent />
</template>

<style lang="scss">
.hello {
  background: red;
}
</style>
`

const staticHtml = compileVueComponent(vueComponent)
```

Output:

```html
<body>
  <div style="background: red;">Hello!</div>
  <div style="background: blue;">World!</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I take it `const staticHtml = compileVueComponent(vueComponent)` doesn't do what you want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to compile Vue.js templates to static HTML and CSS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857376/is-it-possible-to-compile-vue-js-templates-to-static-html-and-css-files)

Comment: Nuxt is already serving static files if you check the output or disable the JS on your page.

Comment: @Bravo compileVueComponent does not exist. That is the functionality I am looking for. Hopefully that clears that up

Comment: @kissu I saw that next does compile static to static files in the dist dir. I am hoping to find a runtime solution using a js library

Comment: At runtime? Not sure how (nor why) you want it to work in that way. You need a trip to a server to generate static files. You can always fetch the `.html` file generated from a Node.js running server on each change or save I guess. What's the purpose of this?

Comment: @kissu This I not for a server application. Currently I'm attempting to build a tool for creating HTML email templates. The templates will only have to be created once ever and then these templates will be added as resources for a backend web api using C#. I have found other similar applications for this as well, but none involve the generated static files being server by a web server directly.

Comment: so, you're after something like a *vue runtime template compiler*?

Comment: Consider explaining your case in the question itself instead of the comment. It doesn't make much sense to use Vue for email templates. It's possible but impractical.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a talk link.

Answer (score 1):

You will not get any benefits from using Vue here especially for email templates, quite the opposite (need back and forth without a lot of plus value).

If you need to create some dynamic views with backend data, you'll better be using [EJS](https://ejs.co/), [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/), [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) or any other backend templating language. You could achieve dynamic rendering, looping on lists, bring your CSS and pretty much everything needed for an email template.

---

This video could also be somehow helpful I guess (didn't watched it myself): https://www.vuemastery.com/conferences/vueconf-us-2021/html-email-with-vue.js/